# solidity - where the token goes if creator balance is less than total supply

Tags: solidity, contract-development, tokens

When I create my token with [Token-Factory](https://github.com/ConsenSys/Token-Factory) , I made a mistake, I set the balance far less than the total supply, the construction is

```
function TOToken() {
    balances[msg.sender] = 100000000; 
    totalSupply = 10000000000;     
    name = "TEST OF TOKEN";     
    decimals = 2;                   
    symbol = "TOT";              
}
```

Although it is just a test token but it confuses me that where is the left token that does not come into my wallet and may I retrieve them back?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*(**NOTE:** in case we are talking about ERC20-like tokens)* 
Tokens don't have their own entity. They are just numbers.

If you didn't "Give" all initial tokens to a contract creator the remaining tokens are just lost like they never existed. There is no function to change initial supply or reassign balance (talking about contracts that you've linked in your question).

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the exact implementation, they may have been assigned to OxO or the crowdsale contract. However, in this case, the most likely outcome is that the tokens don't exist, but if you call the `totalSupply` they will be counted.